# Export to excel and maintain static headers in of grid in excel sheet

Tags: .net, excel, forms, grid

I have the code working to export a grid to a excel sheet . The requirement is to maintain static static headers when you scroll down in excel sheet . How do i achieve this using .net ?  OR do i need to go for 3rd part components (like aspose) ?

```
        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + "StaleReport" + ".xls";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        this.EnableViewState = false;
        StringWriter _stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter _htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(_stringWriter);

        gView.AllowPaging = false;
        gView.AllowSorting = false;

        dt = new DataTable();
        dt = SelectDataandgetallthedata();
        gView.DataSource = dt;
        gView.ShowHeader = true;
        this.Controls.Add(gView);
        gView.DataBind();
        gView.AllowPaging = true;
        gView.AllowSorting = true;

        form.Controls.Add(gView);
        this.Controls.Add(form);

        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        form.RenderControl(_htmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(_stringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in excel vba, it would be:

```
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

However, in .net (after a quick google - not really familiar with .net :) )
have you tried this:

```
sheet.FreezePanes(2, 1);
```